# Unable to open custom module in my drupal 9

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-9

I want to create route to return a simple text in custom module of drupal 9. Whenever I try to open a page it shows an error "Page not found The requested page could not be found."
Here is my code.

mymodule.info.yml

```
name: My First module
type: module
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
description: 'My first module'
```

mymodule.routing.yml

```
 myModule.Content:
  path: '/mymodule'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\myModule\Controller\FirstController::content'
    _title: 'My First Page and Menu Item'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

FirstController.php

```
<?php 

namespace Drupal\myModule\Controller;
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class FirstController extends ControllerBase{
    public function content(){
        return array(
            '#type'=>'markup',
            '#markup'=>t('This is menu linked with custom page'),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the module enabled without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling it has something to do with the way you named your module, which makes drupal not recognize the routes file.

What happens when you change the directory name and module name to `my_module`, rename your info file to `my_module.info.yml` and the routes file to `my_module.routing.yml`? That is also the proper naming convention.

Comment: '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => t('This is menu linked with custom page'),   i have not provided spacing between these lines that's why error is coming . Issue solved thanks for help